# How do I get rid of this TypeInput error?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Sorry I am really new to this so I don't understand some of the syntax
so I tried running this code to see if I could get an app to return 2 variable though text input but this error keeps popping up

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class SayHello(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        #add widgets to window

        # image widget
        self.window.add_widget(Image(source="man.jpg"))
        #Label widget
        self.matsize = Label(text="input size of material?")
        self.window.add_widget(self.matsize)
        # text input widget
        self.user = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.window.add_widget(self.user)
        self.user2 = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.window.add_widget(self.user2)

        #button widget
        self.button = Button(text="GREET")
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)

        return self.window

    def callback(self, instance):
        self.matsize.text = "your material sizer is " + self.user + "x"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SayHello().run()
```

and below is the error

```
File "c:\Users\Abu\Documents\Py Noob\Shop calculator.py", line 33, in callback      
     self.matsize.text = "your material sizer is " + self.user + "x"
 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "TextInput") to str
```

any help I get would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
def callback(self, instance):
        self.matsize.text = "your material sizer is " + self.user + "x"
```

`self.user` is a `TextInput`. `str + TextInput + str` is not looking good.
Maybe you want to use the text from the `TextInput`.

So replace your code by:

```
def callback(self, instance):
        self.matsize.text = "your material sizer is " + self.user.text + "x"
```